# Can I force the Finder's Go Menu to open a new window?

Tags: macos, finder

The Finder's Go menu offers a bunch of shortcuts to commonly used folders, like Applications, Utilities, Downloads, etc.

However, when I try to jump to one of these folders while I already have a Finder window open, Finder takes over my current window to open the special folder.  This happens whether I use the menu or the keyboard shortcut.

Most of the time, I'm trying to open a new window so I can quickly pull up something (like a utility) or to move/copy files between one of the special folders and another location.

Is there a way to have folders from the Go menu open in a new window or a new tab under Mavericks?  I think old versions of OS X had this as a default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can open one directly, but Cmd/n  Cmd/shift/[letter] is pretty quick & will achieve the same result.